# JQuery droppable: get the dragging element properties (height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, droppable

I'm implementing standard JQuery drag&drop functionality, though with some specifics: I use custom generated dragging element (using helper function of draggable() initialization):

```
$("#draggingItem").draggable({
            revert: 'invalid',
            snap: '#myTargetTable td',
            snapMode: "inner",
            snapTolerance: 10,
            zIndex: 100,
            helper: function () {
                var controlContainer = $("<div></div>");
                //fill div content here
                return controlContainer;
            }
        });
```

I want to make droppable area height fit the dragging object.

And here is where my problem occurs: in the "over" method - I can't get height of the dragging element. At the same time the ui parameter works fine for appending to container in "drop" function.

```
$("#myTargetTable td").droppable({
            accept: "#draggingItem",
            over: function (event, ui) {
                var origHeight = $(this).height();
                var uiHeight = $(ui).height();
                if (uiHeight > origHeight) {
                    $(this).attr("origHeight", origHeight);
                    $(this).css("height", uiHeight);
                }
            },
            out: function (event, ui) {
                var origHeight = $(this).attr("origHeight");
                if (origHeight) {
                    $(this).css("height", origHeight);
                    $(this).removeAttr("origHeight");
                }
            },
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).append($(ui));
            }
        });
```

Firebug console shows error message:

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]
```

I also tried using `$(ui.draggable).height()` but it returns the original div that was dragged and not the one created by "helper" function.

Do you have any idea how to get height of dragging element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
ui.helper.height()
```

Both ui.draggable and ui.helper are already jquery objects, so you don't need to wrap them like this $(ui.draggable)